# Logical value does not depend on actual values (M325)

Tags: qt, qml

How should this warning be fixed?

```
Repeater {
    model: n
    SomeItem {
        onValueChanged: if(index === 0) root.myreset()
    }
}
```

(warning is on the `===` comparison)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't reproduce it on *Qt Creator 7.0.1* on Windows using *Desktop Qt 6.3.0 MinGW* kit. According to this bug report [QTCREATORBUG-25917](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-25917) it has been fixed in Qt Creator 7.0.0. That bug report also tells that a workaround for this warning occuring with `index` property in a `delegate` (which is a special property exposed from model to delegate) is to *specify the parent of the object it belongs to*, i.e. `model.index`.

```
Repeater {
    model: n
    SomeItem {
        onValueChanged: if(model.index === 0) root.myreset()
    }
}
```

Comment: To be pedantic, in `model.index`, `model` does not refer to the parent of the object it belongs. It doesn't even refer to the Repeater model. It's just another context property like `index`.